# Rotate rectangle insider rectangle

Tags: math, rotation, geometry

My challenge is to rotate a rectangle inside another rectangle.

Problem description:
[image]

The inner rectangle, let’s call it B, is not allowed to cross the outer rectangle, let’s call it A. But if A is rotated further, so that it might come to a legal position again, it should be rotated to it. So the wanted behavior is to stop rotation before it would cross the border and continue the rotation as soon as B would have a legal position again. B is rotated with a mouse and it might be that not every single degree is calculated extra. So the mouse event might point to 20 degrees and in the next iteration to 40 degrees.

My approach is to solve the problem by calculating and working with rotations. I got the alpha rotation pointing to the mouse. Beta is the rotation from alpha to the right top corner of B.
I calculated the bounding sphere (orange) and its collision points with A (Top Left, Top Right, Right Top, Right Bottom (Left and Bot are not mentioned to not complicate the problem).

Made Calculations:
[image]

With this approach I managed to calculate when I have to stop, but only for the top side and the right side separately. 
For example: Clockwise Rotation -> Top cropping

```
If (B.leftTopCornerRotation < TopLeft ||  B.leftTopCornerRotation > TopRight) {
    Alpha = TopLeft - Beta;
} else if (B.leftBotCornerRotation < TopLeft ||  B. leftBotCornerRotation > TopRight) {
    Alpha = Topleft + Beta  + PI; // + PI rotates the value by 180 degree
} else if (B.rightBotCornerRotation < TopLeft ||  B. rightBotCornerRotation > TopRight) {
    Alpha = TopLeft - Beta + PI;
} else if (B.rightTopCornerRotation < TopLeft ||  B. rightTopCornerRotation > TopRight) {
    Alpha = TopLeft + Beta;
}
```

My first problem is, that if B is out of bounds on more than one line (e.g. top and right) there come situations in which I correct the rotation, so that there is no overstep for the right side, than correct that there is no overstep on the top side. But with the second correction I cause a overstep on the right side. This will lead to an infinite loop.

My second problem is, that this approach seams really complicated.

My question would be, if there is some better / working approach to calculate a valid rotation for B clockwise and counterclockwise, so that it does not overstep the borders. Best case would be when it would look like it just stops at the corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every B corner find angle intervals when it is lies outside of every A edge (infinite edge for simplicity).

Then make union of these 16 intervals (most of them should be empty if B is not large) and exclude resulting interval set from the full circle range.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. My problem with this is only, that it gets complicated really fast. Lets say I rotate clockwise. If i get to a rotation which is not allowed I have to somehow get the nearest allowed value counterclockwise.

Comment: With intervals being ready  you can find the closest interval very fast

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thx.